# Store Product Detail in an array using mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Register_user = mongoose.Schema({
    Gender : String,
    name : String,
    dob : String,
    weight : String,
    height : String,
    userEmail : String,
    cart : Array
})

const register_schema  = mongoose.model("User_registration" , Register_user)

export default register_schema;
```

```
// ^ Add to Cart
export const addToCart = async (req,res) => 
{
    try {
        // ^ Product Data (actually item data that user added to cart) now need to save this in cart array
        const Data = req.body.item;

        // ^ to match user Email and cart Data in only and only his cart array
        const email = req.body.userEmail;

        // ^ finding User based on email
        const user  = await registerSchema.findOne({userEmail : `${email}`})

        if(user)
        {
            // ^ successfully got the user and his cart
          const {cart} = user;

        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error in adding item to cart + ${error.message}`  )
    }
}
```

I want to store item details in cart Array  , whatever item user added to cart i want to store it in mongodb **cart[]** is there a specific method to do this? I tried **safe()**  doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by getting an id of a document and using the `findByIdAndUpdate` method.

```
if (user) {
  // ^ successfully got the user and his cart
  const { _id } = user;
  console.log(_id);
  const { cart } = user;
  await registerSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { cart: [...cart, Data] }).then('done babe');
}
```